# printf in C doesn't work after print a string in VSCode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, printf

I have this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char text[] = "Some random text";
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < sizeof text / sizeof (char); i++) {
        printf("%c", text[i]);
        counter++;
    }
    printf("\n%d", counter);
}
```

But the VSCode console only shows the text ("Some random text"). The printf for 'counter' is not working.

If I execute it out of VSCode, by clicking the .exe file, it works fine (in DevC++ too).
Any idea?

Comment: Side note: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: sizeof(char) is 1 by definition.

Comment: I search before asking! And no answer helped me

Comment: @gonza5913 please confirm that the duplicate doesn't apply in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The `printf()` function is buffered, you need a new line or `fflush(stdout)` to flush it.

Just try

```
printf("\n%d\n", counter);
```

instead.

Comment: Sorry, this not work. I add a fflush(stdout) and some '\n' and didn't work. Same result

Comment: I didn't see your loop, you are including the null terminator. `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition, and `sizeof` doesn't give you the length of the string, but the length of the array of characters. Literal strings have on extra implied item, namely the 0 terminator. You should subtract 1 or use `for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; ++i)`

Comment: Great, thats works! I'm really sorry for the sizeof (char). I did an example with integer's array and i forgot to deleted it. Thanks!